# If-statement fail in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

For several hours now am I trying to make a simple game, but one if-statement is failing:

```
function checkDiagonaal() {
    if (document.getElementById("11").src.indexOf("o.png") &&
        document.getElementById("22").src.indexOf("x.png") &&
        document.getElementById("33").src.indexOf("o.png"))
    {
        winnaar = true;
    }
}
```

The condition is not true, yet the variable `winnaar` is set on `true`. I don't see what I am doing wrong. Very probably just a little mistake.

I also tried this code:

```
if(document.getElementById("11").src === "images/o.png")
```

but this returns false (even when the condition is true). I would like to know why?

Comment: "The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex,
returns -1 if the value is not found." -- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: @EugeneP: They can in HTML5.

Comment: yeah. was a bit curious about it. just read post. thanks. anyway) @CBroe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `...indexOf(...) >= 0` in such conditions.

Answer (score 1):

indexOf returns -1 when the value is not found, -1 is truthy

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)(great resource!):

> "The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String
>   object of the first occurrence of the specified value [...] **returns -1**
>   if the value is not found."

When statements get big they become a bit unreadable, it might be fine now, but if you need to add more checks, I would suggest a different approach:

```
function checkDiagonaal() {
  var ids = [11,22,33];
  var strs = ['o.png','x.png','o.png'];
  var winnar = ids.every(function(id,i) {
    return document.getElementById(id).src.indexOf(strs[i]) > -1;
  });
}
```